# Best performance for paging query when using multiple statements in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is a bit complicated query but let me elaborate,
i have got multiple filter parameters in my procedure,
also  a view named Vw1 and its regarded my main object in query that most of the filter parameters are filtered against this view that is located in another server,then i need to compare this view to another table and check two sides columns for possible conflict and then check if there is any conflict.
you can see my query below

```
ALTER  PROC [dbo].[spGetAyandehVagozariWithConflict]
    @Take INT,
    @Skip INT,
    @FromVagozariDate NVARCHAR(10),
    @ToVagozariDate NVARCHAR(10),
    @OrderBankCode NVARCHAR(4)=null,
    @OrderBrCode NVARCHAR(7)=null,
    @BenefBrCode NVARCHAR(4)=null,
    @FromAmount NVARCHAR(50)=null,
    @ToAmount NVARCHAR(50)=null,
    @CheqSerie NVARCHAR(50)=null,
    @CheqSerial NVARCHAR(10)=null,
    @CheqStatus NVARCHAR(4)=null,
    @CreditorNationalCode VARCHAR(20)=NULL,
    @CheqType NVARCHAR(4)=null,
    @BenefAccn NVARCHAR(13)=null,
    @FromMatDate NVARCHAR(10)=null,
    @ToMatDate NVARCHAR(10)=null,
    @FromTaeenVaziatDate NVARCHAR(10)=null,
    @ToTaeenVaziatDate NVARCHAR(10)=NULL,
    @HasConflict VARCHAR(4)=null,
    @TotalCnt INT OUTPUT,
    @SUM BIGINT OUTPUT
    AS
  BEGIN

  DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

  IF(NULLIF(@FromVagozariDate,'') IS null)
  SET @FromVagozariDate='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@ToVagozariDate,'') IS null)
  SET @ToVagozariDate='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@OrderBrCode,'') IS null)
  SET @OrderBrCode='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@OrderBankCode,'') IS null)
  SET @OrderBankCode='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@BenefBrCode,'') IS null)
  SET @BenefBrCode='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@FromAmount,'') IS null)
  SET @FromAmount='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@ToAmount,'') IS null)
  SET @ToAmount='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@CheqSerie,'') IS null)
  SET @CheqSerie='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@CheqSerial,'') IS null)
  SET @CheqSerial='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@CheqStatus,'') IS null)
  SET @CheqStatus='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@CheqType,'') IS null)
  SET @CheqType='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@BenefAccn,'') IS null)
  SET @BenefAccn='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@ToMatDate,'') IS null)
  SET @ToMatDate='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@FromMatDate,'') IS null)
  SET @FromMatDate='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@FromTaeenVaziatDate,'') IS null)
  SET @FromTaeenVaziatDate='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@ToTaeenVaziatDate,'') IS null)
  SET @ToTaeenVaziatDate='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@HasConflict,'') IS null)
  SET @HasConflict='NULL'

  IF(NULLIF(@CreditorNationalCode,'') IS null)
  SET @CreditorNationalCode='NULL'


  IF @FromVagozariDate<>'NULL'
  BEGIN
  SET @FromVagozariDate=REPLACE(@FromVagozariDate,'/','')
  END

  IF @ToVagozariDate<>'NULL'
  BEGIN
  SET @ToVagozariDate=REPLACE(@ToVagozariDate,'/','')
  END

  IF @FromMatDate<>'NULL'
  BEGIN
  SET @FromMatDate=REPLACE(@FromMatDate,'/','')

  END

  IF @ToMatDate<>'NULL'
  BEGIN
  SET @ToMatDate=REPLACE(@ToMatDate,'/','')

  END

  IF @FromTaeenVaziatDate<>'NULL'
  BEGIN
  SET @FromTaeenVaziatDate=REPLACE(@FromTaeenVaziatDate,'/','')
   SET @FromTaeenVaziatDate=SUBSTRING(@FromTaeenVaziatDate,3,6)

  END

  IF @ToTaeenVaziatDate<>'NULL'
  BEGIN
  SET @ToTaeenVaziatDate=REPLACE(@ToTaeenVaziatDate,'/','')
   SET @ToTaeenVaziatDate=SUBSTRING(@ToTaeenVaziatDate,3,6)
  END

  IF @OrderBankCode<>'NULL'
  BEGIN
  --SET @OrderBankCode='0'+@OrderBankCode;
  SET @OrderBankCode=dbo.LeftPad(@OrderBankCode,'0',3)
  END

  IF(@BenefBrCode<>'NULL')
  BEGIN
  SET @BenefBrCode=dbo.LeftPad(@BenefBrCode,'0',4)
  END 

  IF(@OrderBrCode<>'NULL')
  BEGIN
  SET @OrderBrCode=dbo.LeftPad(@OrderBrCode,'0',4)
  END 


  SET @Query=@Query+N'
   SELECT  * 
   INTO #Vw1 
   FROM [LinkedServer].DbName.dbo.Vw1  vd
   where (vd.mat_date BETWEEN '+''''+@FromMatDate+''''+' AND'+''''+ @ToMatDate+''''+' OR ('+''''+@FromMatDate+''''+' =''NULL'' AND '+''''+@ToMatDate+''''+' =''NULL'' )) AND
    (dbo.LeftPad(vd.order_bank_code,''0'',3)= '+''''+@OrderBankCode+''''+' OR '+''''+@OrderBankCode+''''+' =''NULL'') AND
    (dbo.LeftPad(vd.order_brcode,''0'',4)= '+''''+@OrderBrCode+''''+' OR '+''''+@OrderBrCode+''''+' =''NULL'')  AND
    (dbo.LeftPad(vd.Benef_br_code,''0'',4)= '+''''+@BenefBrCode+''''+' OR '+''''+@BenefBrCode+''''+' =''NULL'')  AND
    (substring(vd.amount, patindex(''%[^0]%'',vd.amount), 10) BETWEEN '+''''+@FromAmount+''''+' AND '+''''+@ToAmount+''''+' OR ('+''''+@FromAmount+''''+' =''NULL'' AND '+''''+@ToAmount+''''+' =''NULL''))  AND
    (RTRIM(LTRIM(vd.chq_serie))= '+''''+@CheqSerie+''''+' OR '+''''+@CheqSerie+''''+' =''NULL'')  AND
    (RTRIM(LTRIM(vd.chq_serial))= '+''''+@CheqSerial+''''+' OR '+''''+@CheqSerial+''''+' =''NULL'')  AND
    (vd.Chq_stat= '+''''+@CheqStatus+''''+' OR '+''''+@CheqStatus+''''+' in (''NULL'',''-1''))  AND
    (vd.chq_type= '+''''+@CheqType+''''+' OR '+''''+@CheqType+''''+' =''NULL'')  AND
    (vd.benef_acno= '+''''+@BenefAccn+''''+' OR '+''''+@BenefAccn+''''+' =''NULL'')  AND
    ((vd.taeen_vaziat_date is null  AND ('+''''+@CheqStatus+''''+'=''-1'')) or('+''''+@CheqStatus+''''+'<>''-1'') )  AND
    (vd.vagozari_date BETWEEN '+''''+@FromVagozariDate+''''+' AND '+''''+@ToVagozariDate+''''+' OR ('+''''+@FromVagozariDate+''''+' =''NULL'' AND '+''''+@ToVagozariDate+''''+' =''NULL''))  AND
    (vd.taeen_vaziat_date BETWEEN '+''''+@FromTaeenVaziatDate+''''+' AND '+''''+@ToTaeenVaziatDate+''''+' OR ('+''''+@ToTaeenVaziatDate+''''+' =''NULL'' AND '+''''+@FromTaeenVaziatDate+''''+' =''NULL''))  
    order by system_no

    select distinct cast(benef_acno as bigint) benef_acno
    into #acno
    from #Vw1 

    select ACNO,CUSTNO
    into #ACTINFO
    from [LinkServer1].[Db1].[dbo].[ACTINFO] af
    where accno_id in (select * from #acno)

    select [ECONOMIC-CODE],CUSTNO,FIRSTNAME +'' ''+LASTNAME CUSTNAME
    into #CUSTINFO
    from [LinkServer1].[Db1].[dbo].[CUSTINFO] 
    where CustNo_Id in (select cast(CUSTNO as bigint) from #ACTINFO)



   SELECT 
    vd.*,
    ct.Title CheqTypeTitle,
    af.CUSTNO,cf.CUSTNAME,
    --'''' as CUSTNO,'''' CUSTNAME,
    cs.Status CheqStatusTitle,
    av.Id AyandehVagozariId,
    p.ParticipantName BenefBankName,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(vd.vagozari_date,'''') <>  COALESCE(REPLACE(av.VagozariDate,''/'',''''),vd.vagozari_date,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END VagozariDateHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(dbo.LeftPad(vd.order_bank_code,''0'',3),'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Order_Bank_Code,dbo.LeftPad(vd.order_bank_code,''0'',3),'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END OrderBankCodeHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(dbo.LeftPad(vd.order_brcode,''0'',4),'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Order_brCode,dbo.LeftPad(vd.order_brcode,''0'',4),'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END OrderBrCodeHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(dbo.LeftPad(vd.Benef_br_code,''0'',4),'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Benef_Br_Code,dbo.LeftPad(vd.Benef_br_code,''0'',4),'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END BenefBrCodeHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(substring(vd.amount, patindex(''%[^0]%'',vd.amount), 10),'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Amount,substring(vd.amount, patindex(''%[^0]%'',vd.amount), 10),'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END AmountHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(vd.chq_serie,'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Chq_serie,vd.chq_serie,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END CheqSerieHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(RTRIM(LTRIM(vd.chq_serial)),'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Chq_Serial,RTRIM(LTRIM(vd.chq_serial)),'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END CheqSerialHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(vd.chq_type,'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Chq_Type,vd.chq_type,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END CheqTypeHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(vd.benef_acno,'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Benef_Acno,vd.benef_acno,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END BenefAcnoHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(vd.mat_date,'''') <>  COALESCE(REPLACE(av.Mat_Date,''/'',''''),vd.mat_date,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END MatDateHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(cf.CUSTNO,'''') <>  COALESCE(av.CUSTNO,cf.CUSTNO COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END CustNoHasConflict,
     --CASE WHEN ISNULL(vd.taeen_vaziat_date,'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Taeen_Vaziat_Date,vd.taeen_vaziat_date,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END TaeenVaziatDateHasConflict,
     0 as TaeenVaziatDateHasConflict,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL(vd.Chq_stat,'''') <>  COALESCE(av.Chq_Status,vd.Chq_stat,'''') THEN  1  ELSE 0 END CheqStatusHasConflict
     --0 as VagozariDateHasConflict,
     --0 as OrderBankCodeHasConflict, 
     --0 as OrderBrCodeHasConflict,
     --0 as BenefBrCodeHasConflict,
     --0 as AmountHasConflict, 
     --0 as CheqSerieHasConflict,
     --0 as CheqSerialHasConflict,
     --0 as CheqTypeHasConflict,
     --0 as BenefAcnoHasConflict,
     --0 as MatDateHasConflict,
     --0 as TaeenVaziatDateHasConflict

    INTO #temp
    FROM #vw_faranam_vagozari_chakavak vd   
    LEFT JOIN #ACTINFO af on vd.benef_acno=af.ACNO COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
    LEFT JOIN #CUSTINFO cf on af.CUSTNO=cf.CUSTNO COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
    LEFT JOIN [AyandehVagozari] av   ON av.SystemNo=vd.system_no 
    LEFT JOIN [Cheque_Type_Biha] ct ON ct.Code=vd.chq_type
    LEFT JOIN [ChequeStatusForBiha] cs ON cs.Id=vd.Chq_stat
    LEFT JOIN [Participant] p ON ''0''+p.ParticipantCode=vd.order_bank_code

    WHERE (cf.[ECONOMIC-CODE]= '+''''+@CreditorNationalCode+''''+' OR '+''''+@CreditorNationalCode+''''+' =''NULL'')  
    order by vd.system_no


    DELETE  t FROM(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by system_no order by AyandehVagozariId desc) rn FROM 
    #temp
    )t
    where rn>1  


    SELECT *,
    case when (VagozariDateHasConflict=1 or OrderBankCodeHasConflict=1 or OrderBrCodeHasConflict =1 OR BenefBrCodeHasConflict=1
      or AmountHasConflict=1 or CheqSerieHasConflict=1 or CheqSerialHasConflict=1 or CustNoHasConflict=1
      or CheqStatusHasConflict=1 or CheqTypeHasConflict=1 or BenefAcnoHasConflict=1 or MatDateHasConflict=1 or TaeenVaziatDateHasConflict=1)
       then 1 else 0 end HasConflict
    INTO #TmpResult
    FROM #temp
    order by system_no
```

--**here is where i filter my last parameter but it seems too late..because alot of records       already involved** !

```
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY system_no) RowNumber
    into #finalTemp
    FROM
    #TmpResult
    where (HasConflict=1 and '+''''+@HasConflict+''''+'=''1'')
    OR (HasConflict=0 and '+''''+@HasConflict+''''+'=''0'')
    OR ('+''''+@HasConflict+''''+'=''NULL'')
    order by system_no

     SELECT @Total=@@ROWCOUNT

     select @Sum=isnull(SUM(cast(amount as bigint)),0) from
     #finalTemp

     select * from 
     #finalTemp
     WHERE RowNumber >'+CAST(@Skip AS NVARCHAR(10))+' AND RowNumber<=('+CAST(@Skip+@Take AS NVARCHAR(10))+')

   '

   PRINT @Query

   EXEC sp_executesql @Query,N'@Total int output,@Sum bigint output',@TotalCnt OUTPUT,@SUM OUTPUT

  END
```

due to performance issues i had to write it in dynamic way,But the problem is that i could not wrap my head around paging in this query, bacause as you see i should put paging line in the end of query because `@HasConflict` parameters exist and i cannot check it earlier,and in this way my paging seems pointless because i'm dealing with huge load of data ...

also i cannot use offset for paging because my sql version is too old ...

Comment: `and '+''''+@HasConflict+''''+'=''1''`? What is that mess meant to actually mean? `''1''` isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: because i am using dynamic query i need to write in this way.

Comment: Then parametrise it and don't leave yourselves wide open to injection. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: i red your article and appreciate your advise  @Larnu ,i will follow your guides,